# DisplayPort does not function when booting normally

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, hdmi, amd-graphics

My system:
AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK (if that has any effect)
Radeon RX 7600
Running Ubuntu 22.04
Two monitors (1080p, 75hz)

I'm trying to make the switch from Windows to Ubuntu. For now, I have a dual boot with Windows. 
After reloading into Windows (and then switching back), I noticed that one of the monitors that I had wouldn't work. Furthermore, the second monitor, which is connected via DisplayPort (the first uses HDMI) would be extremely zoomed in. While I could type (and managed to log in), it's impossible to do anything productive.

(Note: the HDMI output works on my 4K TV, but not the 1080p monitor. I'm guessing it might have to do with framerate but so far none of my guesses have been right.)

When booting through Recovery Mode, however, the HDMI monitor would act as normal while the DisplayPort monitor has no graphics at all.

While I can live with the one monitor, it is annoying that I have to boot through recovery mode in order to see enough of the screen to use it. I've tried to fix the issue myself but am not the best with computers (and ended up making more issues to fix).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.